# How to make JOIN in parse plateform?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I have to tables and need to know if I can apply join to get required result.

I have to two collections one is "User" and second is "Follow".

User collection:

- objectId
- name
- username

Follow collection:

- objectId
- followerUser
- followingUser

I am creating search people API using "name" and in result I want to know if I can check if I follow that user or not.

Is it possible to apply join for this? and get result in one query?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!